# when doing math with continuous functions: the limit of a sequence of continuous functions is not necessarily continuous

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

In calculus, when doing math with continuous functions: the limit of a sequence of continuous functions is not necessarily continuous, I need an example of this statement.

Answer (score 2):

What about $f_n(x)=x^n$ on $[0,1]$?

Comment: I mean it may not be continuous

Comment: Isn't the limit discontinuous?

Comment: @Yaya Please check this first.

Comment: The limit is $f(x)=\begin{cases}0,x\in[0,1)\\1,x=1\end{cases}$.

Comment: $f_n(x)=x^n$ on $[0,1]$ no convergence $f(x)$ @ChrisCuster

Comment: $sup_{[0,1)}|x^n-0|=1$ other than $0$ $=>$ $f_n(x)$ not convergence  $f(x)$

Comment: @Yaya: The word **limit** in your question refers to **pointwise** convergence. For **uniform** convergence (which is what you're talking about in your latest comment), the limit of a sequence of continuous functions **is** continuous.